# In python, Is it possible to get the path of the invoked from the invoked file?

Tags: python, path, filepath, module-path

I want to invoke config.py from ./, but I want config.py to recognize the path where it is located ("./second/config.py")

I want to invoke config.py from "./" and I want config.py to recognize and read file.json, but I dont want to send any paths as argument, nor append "./second" to sys.path.
Is there a piece of code that can allow config.py recognize its relative path, and in this way join this path to the json's filename and read it?

```
./
├── main.py
└── second
      ├── config.py
      └── file.json
```

I tried this on config.py

```
def test():
 print(pathlib.Path().absolute())
 print(os.getcwd())
```

However, it returns

```
./
```

and I am expecting it to return

```
/second/config.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this two os methods together

```
import os
full_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + os.path.basename(__file__)
```